# Rails - How to override ActiveRecord::Base destroy method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a class called `Rule` that inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`. I would like to override the inherited destroy method to "soft delete" the record in the database if we pass in an option to do so. I was thinking something like this:

```
def self.destroy(soft: false)
  soft ? soft_delete : super
end
```

I'm attempting to call `super` when no options are passed to `destroy` and call a method `soft_delete` if `soft: true` is passed to `destroy`.

This works to soft delete a rule when passing `soft: true`, but when I pass no parameters it gives me a wrong number of arguments error:

```
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.4.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `destroy': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) (ArgumentError)
```

Am I overriding this incorrectly?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `super` Ruby automatically includes the arguments passed in. So when you call `destroy` with no parameters, `super` is being called as `super(soft: false)`.

Of course, this is wrong, b/c the ActiveRecord destroy method does not take any arguments.

So this works:

```rb
def self.destroy(soft: false)
  soft ? soft_delete : super() # no args included in the super method
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this gem: `gem "discard", "1.2.1"`

and you can do soft delete with discard

```
user = User.kept.find_by(id: @params[:id])


user.discard!
```